# AWS RDS Auto Minor Updates With Zero Downtime

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, oracle, amazon-rds

Is it possible to run AWS RDS Auto Minor Updates for either MySql or Oralce without having downtime?

Currently I'm running Oralce v19+ and MySql 5.7+ on multi AZ clusters.

Both clusters went offline during the update process, varying between 150 to 260 seconds with miniscule data amounts.

I've looked at AWS ideas on this and they appear very convoluted.

Has anyone cracked this chestnut before?

Comment: Thanks Alex - I was thinking a blue green deployment model, and AWS RDS Oracle do you offer something along these lines, but again, not a clean implementation.

Comment: What you might be able to do is use EventBridge to monitor for these minor upgrades. Then temporarily failover with Route53 to a S3 bucket with a friendly message!

Comment: Nope - we need a 24/7 service, just like AWS is meant to offer 

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Multi-AZ but a minor upgrade for RDS will always upgrade both instances at the same time. So you will always have some downtime. I suspect the reason behind this is that the instances must be on the same minor version to perform replication.

If you switch to Aurora MySQL, this service has [zero-downtime patching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.Patching.html#AuroraMySQL.Updates.ZDP).

For MySQL you might be able to use [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/improving-application-availability-with-amazon-rds-proxy/) to get a faster failover time (depending on your usecase).

For Oracle I think the situation is a bit harder to implement because it depends on the support that AWS offers on that front.